# Which is better when creating multiple Publishers in Combine? AnyCancellable for each or Set<AnyCancellable> with .store(in: &self.cancellableSet)?

Tags: ios, combine

I'm somewhat new to Combine and reactive programming in general. I think I've come across two different ways to do the same thing, but I'm wondering why I should chose one over the other.

I have a simple model that stores and publishes values related to the Apple Watch status. Below are the two different ways I think I'm doing the same thing.

In this first approach, I'm using a separate `AnyCancellable?` for each `Publisher`:

```
class WatchConnectivityModel: ObservableObject {

    init() {
        activationState = WCSession.default.activationState
        isWatchAppInstalled = WCSession.default.isWatchAppInstalled
        isComplicationEnabled = WCSession.default.isComplicationEnabled

        assignPublishers()
    }

    @Published var activationState: WCSessionActivationState
    @Published var isWatchAppInstalled: Bool
    @Published var isComplicationEnabled: Bool

    private var activationStateStream: AnyCancellable?
    private var isWatchAppInstalledStream: AnyCancellable?
    private var isComplicationEnabledStream: AnyCancellable?

    private func assignPublishers() {
        activationStateStream = WCSession.default
            .publisher(for: \.activationState)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.activationState, on: self)

        isWatchAppInstalledStream = WCSession.default
            .publisher(for: \.isWatchAppInstalled)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.isWatchAppInstalled, on: self)

        isComplicationEnabledStream = WCSession.default
            .publisher(for: \.isComplicationEnabled)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.isComplicationEnabled, on: self)
    }
}
```

Here is my second approach, but instead of separate `AnyCancellable?` objects I'm using a single `Set<AnyCancellable>` along with `.store(in: &self.cancellableSet)` on each `Publisher`:

```
class WatchConnectivityModel: ObservableObject {

    init() {
        activationState = WCSession.default.activationState
        isWatchAppInstalled = WCSession.default.isWatchAppInstalled
        isComplicationEnabled = WCSession.default.isComplicationEnabled

        assignPublishers()
    }

    @Published var activationState: WCSessionActivationState
    @Published var isWatchAppInstalled: Bool
    @Published var isComplicationEnabled: Bool

    private var cancellableSet: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    private func assignPublishers() {
        _ = WCSession.default
            .publisher(for: \.activationState)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.activationState, on: self)
            .store(in: &self.cancellableSet)

        _ = WCSession.default
            .publisher(for: \.isWatchAppInstalled)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.isWatchAppInstalled, on: self)
            .store(in: &self.cancellableSet)

        _ = WCSession.default
            .publisher(for: \.isComplicationEnabled)
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .assign(to: \.isComplicationEnabled, on: self)
            .store(in: &self.cancellableSet)
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that the first approach would be better if I need to manually do something to one of the three specific streams, however I don't need to in this case. Other than that, is there anything that makes one of these approaches a better choice than the other? Is there anything major that I'm missing when it comes to memory management going with one over the other?

The second one seems a little weird to me because of the whole `_ =` part, because that seems like an extra artifact that's hard to explain: why am I assigning this whole thing to nothing? The first option avoids that possible confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no particular reason to create a separate variable for each subscription, if all subscriptions will be destroyed at the same time.

Note also that you don't need to use a `Set<AnyCancellable>`. An array works just as well or better:

```
private var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []
```

You don't need “the whole `_ =` part” at all. The `store(in:)` method returns `Void`, so the compiler knows the return value can be ignored.